# Проблема с display: table

Tags: css

Есть такой пример [на jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Idaho37/bbYSS/)

```css
.table {
    display: table;
}
.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="column-left">
        <img src="http://cv1.litres.ru/static/bookimages/08/35/44/08354418.bin.dir/08354418.cover_250.jpg" width="70" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">— Я наблюдал за этой драмой с вертолета. На пакистанское побережье словно напал чудовищный водяной монстр. Темно-зеленая стена, покрытая серебристой пеной, неистовым потоком обрушилась на Карачи, деловую столицу Пакистана, сметая с лица земли большие здания и маленькие дома, словно они были из папье-маше. Люсьена, это было поистине жуткое зрелище. Жители города выбежали на улицы и бросил
```

как сделать, что бы 2 колонки были на одном уровне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.table { display: table; }
.table > div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```